# gridview findcontrol returning empty ""

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, gridview, findcontrol

i am trying to read from a textbox within a gridview by using this code

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            string textBoxText = ((TextBox)row.FindControl("numTC")).Text;
            Response.Write(textBoxText);

        }
    }
```

this code keeps returning "" (empty)

any idea why this is hapenning?

Thanks

Comment: Does it have any value ?

Comment: i am adding the values manually trough the website, its reading them all as "" and not null

Comment: @Karl: are you using visual studio to debug?

Comment: yes, thats how im finding what it returns

Comment: When you click the button are the values in the Textboxes on the page changing back to blank?

Comment: yes they are, does it mean something?

Comment: @Karl: are you doing databinding of grid in code or is it done automatically? could you show us your gridview asp?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure that you are not re-binding the GridView on the PostBack of the page. This may be the issue.

**EDITS**

Make sure that the code for Binding the GridView is within the code below:

C#

```
if ( !Page.IsPostBack ){
    // Code to bind the control
}
```

VB

```
If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
    ' Code to bind the control
End If
```

Otherwise what happens is that the controls is "rebuilt" and the values are all lost within the TextBox's

Comment: the gridview is binding on page_load, and when i click the button it seems to be re loading the page, how can i arrange that?

Comment: Where have you added this code? Don't add it to the button click

Comment: then i understood you wrong, where should i add it? 
should i do it where it is doing the databind of the gridview?

Comment: Yes, were you are binding the data to the GridView.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:**

*For testing purposes, try doing GridView1.DataBind(); at the begining of your method.*

Try debugging like this:

Set a breakpoint at the end of the Button1_Click method.

Run the site in debug mode (F5).

When executions stops at end of Button1_Click, open the Immediate Window located at bottom of screen.

Type there:

GridView1.Rows and see if it contains the number of rows it should.

Should be something like:

System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowCollection}
    Count: 53 <-- number of rows

If it does return more than 0 rows then type:

GridView1.Rows[0].Controls and see if it returns the right number of controls on a row.

I could access controls on a row directly using GridView1.Rows[2].Controls[n] where n is the order of the control in the row.

Also try (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[0].FindControl("numTC") and see what it returns.

Comment: ive done as you said, the number of rows shows as 79, and the (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[0].FindControl("numTC")
still returns ""

Comment: @Karl: the only thing i can think of is that the control you are searching has a different ID from "numTC", i made that mistake once and didn't notice :)

Comment: ive tried that too..but unfortunatley it wasnt the case, ill keep trying to see whats wrong, thanks anyway

Comment: @Karl: does GridView1.Rows[0].FindControl("numTC") return null?

Comment: when i do response.write, it just returns System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox

Comment: @Karl: i mean to use the command GridView1.Rows[0].FindControl("numTC") in Immediate Window, if it returns null it means it couldn't find the control. Does it return null?

Comment: problem solved, it was because the data was rebinding every time i pressed the button, thanks for your help